# Únterlegen vs. unterlégen

Tags: prefix, separable-verb

I have a question about these two verbs with different stress and meaning. I thought, that stress determines, wether the prefix is separable or inseparable.

But in the Duden, both verbs are conjugated as if they have inseparable prefixes:

> [únterlegen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/unterlegen_auslegen_darunterlegen) – [unterlégen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/unterlegen_besiegt_ueberwaeltigt)
>   ich unterlege – ich unterlege
>   du unterlegst – du unterlegst
>   …

Is it right or not in the given case? Could it be that prefixes such as *durch-, über-, um-, unter-, wieder-,* or *wider* are accented/stressed, but they are inseparable?

Comment: Interessant! Der Duden hat *unterlegt* in der Tabelle aber *untergelegt* im Beispiel.

Comment: I somehow cannot see two verbs here - I see one verb in a literal and in a metaphorical usage. I also do not see two different stresses. Are you maybe referring to *unterlegen* as the participle of *unterliegen*, which indeed has a different stress?

Answer (score 6):

What you are seeing here is apparently a corner case on the journey of a verb + preposition to a prefixed verb.

> Ich lege ein Kissen unter deinen Kopf.

is the verb *legen* plus the preposition *unter.* All fine, no problem.

> Ich unterlege deinen Kopf mit einem Kissen.

doesn’t work separated, as in

> <del>Ich lege deinen Kopf mit einem Kissen unter.</del>

(at least not in my world), while

> Ich lege deinem Kopf ein Kissen unter.

works very well.

In perfect, they look like this:

> Ich habe deinen Kopf mit einem Kissen unterlegt
>
> Ich habe deinem Kopf ein Kissen untergelegt

Both seem to work.

So, apparently, there seems to be a difference between transitive and intransitive usage of *unterlegen* – the transitive usage uses the verb in separable form, while intransitive usage takes the inseparable form.

There is quite a number of verbs that are both separable and inseparable and have a different meaning in both cases like *umfahren* (e.g., “Ich umfahre den Fussgänger” vs. “Ich fahre den Fussgänger um”), but *unterlegen* is  the first one where I realize that separability might depend on transitive/non-transitive usage.

Looking at my answer after some time, I might have chosen a better example: *unterlegen* may be used with cushions and heads (and works), but is mostly used as a “technical” action to adjust something in height, like in:

> Der Schrank wackelt, da müssen wir wohl was unterlegen
>
> Der Bolzen ist zu lang. Ich unterlege da wohl eine Scheibe.

Answer (score 5):

There are different meanings of "unterlegen" which are distinguished by accentuation in their infinitve. When in use, the preposition "unter" is either split and moved to the end (únterlegen) or remains unseparated (unterlégen)

### únterlegen:

> *verb*: "to put/lay under" / "to shim"
>
> *usage*: "Ich lege dem Patienten ein Kissen unter." / "Ich habe dem Patienten ein Kissen untergelegt."

### unterlégen:

> *verb*: "to underlay sth. with sth." / "to prove sth." / "to justify sth."
>
> *synonyms*: etw. untermauern / beweisen / begründen
>
> *usage*: "Ich unterlege das mit einem Zitat."
>
> ---
>
> *verb*: "to accompany with sth."
>
> *synonyms*: etw. auskleiden / untermalen / umrahmen / begleiten
>
> usage: "Er unterlegte seine Rede mit Musik." / "Er hat seine Rede mit Musik unterlegt."
>
> ---

Attention - the following is not related to the infinitive "unterlegen"

> *participle of "unterliegen"*: "being inferior / defeated / outgunned"
>
> *usage*: "Ich unterlag ihr" / "Ich war ihr unterlegen." / "Ich bin ihr unterlegen." / "Ich werde ihr unterliegen."

Answer (score 0):

This should be an error on Duden’s side. It conflicts with the rule as you said and also sounds really strange to my ear. As a native speaker I’d rather say: “Ich lege unter”, as is consistent with the rules, instead of: “Ich únterlege”.

Answer (score -3):

In dem Duden-link geht es

- einmal um das Verb *unterlegen* (z.B. Ich werde dem Bauteil ein Holzstück unterlegen.)
- und einmal um das Adjektiv *unterlegen* (z.B. Der Perserkönig war Alexander unterlegen.)

Ich (auch Muttersprachler) würde das Verb *unterlegen* vor allem bei technischen Beschreibungen verwenden. Bei Schraubverbindungen gibt es z.B. eine Unterleg-Scheibe (*washer*).

Comment: Servus und willkommen beim Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache. Da du die [Tour] schon genommen hast, bleibt mir nur, dich auf das [Help] hinzuweisen, wo alle Fragen, wie die Seite funktioniert, beantwortet werden. Übrigens ist dein Beitrag unten rechts schon von deinem Gravatar unterschrieben, deswegen sind keine wetieren Unterschriften nötig ;)

Comment: Übrigens zum Inhalt deines Beitrags: Auch *unterlegen* im Alexandersinne ist ein Verb. Beispiel: »Alexander *unterliegt* dem Perserkönig. Du stellst einen Dualismus auf, der in dieser Form nicht existiert.

Comment: @Jan KS-Modus: Das mit dem Perserkönig war andersrum. Nur der Korrektheit halber ;)

Comment: und natürlich geht es in dem Duden-link *nicht* um das verb "unterliegen" mit seiner Partizipform "unterlegen". Das ist ein anderes Verb.